# Sympy nsimplify() is returning (x + 3) in an equation instead of simplifying

Tags: python, math, sympy

```
From sympy import *

x = symbols('x')

nsimplify(3 * (x+3)**2 + 2 * (x+3) - 4)
```

nsimplify is returning `2 * x + 3 * (x+3)**2 + 2`
Which is technically correct, but why isn't it further simplifying to `3 * x**2 + 20 * x + 29`?

Tried inputting it a bunch of different ways, even this.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import implemented_function

x = symbols('x')

f = implemented_function('f', lambda x: 3 * x**2 + 2 * x - 4)
lam_f = lambdify(x, f(x))
print(lam_f(x+3))
```

And got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `nsimplify` when I think you wanted to use `simplify`. These are two different functions. The `nsimplify` function attempts to turn floats into exact rational numbers e.g.:

```
In [11]: 1/3
Out[11]: 0.3333333333333333

In [12]: nsimplify(1/3)
Out[12]: 1/3
```

The `simplify` function is for exact simplification of symbolic expressions e.g.:

```
In [13]: expr
Out[13]: 2*x + 3*(x + 3)**2 + 2

In [14]: simplify(expr)
Out[14]: 3*x**2 + 20*x + 29
```

More precisely though what you really want here is `expand`:

```
In [16]: expand(expr)
Out[16]: 3*x**2 + 20*x + 29
```

I recommend reading the SymPy tutorial. Here is the page on simplification which explains both `expand` and `simplify`:

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/simplification.html

Here are the docs for `nsimplify`:

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#sympy.simplify.simplify.nsimplify